# Jamaica Tourist visa for Indian Citizen

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, jamaica

Can you please guide me about Jamaica Tourist visa for Indian citizen whether they need visa or not.

Answer (score 2):

Indian citizens do not require a visa to travel to Jamaica.

Source: http://www.pica.gov.jm/immigration/general-immigration-information/requirements-for-travel-to-jamaica/

Comment: @Rashmi No need for thanks :-) If the answer satisfied your question please accept it by ✅

Comment: @rashmi Make sure you travel on one ticket so your bags are checked through. And don't go via the US since then you'd need a visa for the US. This will limit your options quite fairly.